# Self-Contained Applications, built in Java

Tags: java, java-9, self-contained, java-module

I've watched a few online presentations that briefly mentioned self-contained applications in Java 9, but I have a question that I would like cleared up.

With the new module system, you're now allowed to only include the minimum amount of code required to run your application.  However, does the system that wishes to run the application still require the JRE, or is that something that can be included in the base module within the program?

I suspect it's the latter, as the page ([here](https://java.com/en/download/)) to download the newest version of Java still shows version 8_151.

TL;DR - Using Java 9, is it possible to create a self-contained executable that can be executed on a system without the JRE/Java installed?

Comment: java always (at least for the latest versions for sure) allowed packets to be packaged with a specific JRE. With the modular system of java 9, the volume of data you need to include is simply reduced. In previous releases this was achieved with profiles.

Comment: FYI, besides the two good Answers about `jlink` and `javapackager`, you will find background info in  [*Java Client Roadmap Update* of 2018-03](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javaclientroadmapupdate2018mar-4414431.pdf) and [*Java Is Still Free*](https://medium.com/@javachampions/java-is-still-free-c02aef8c9e04).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## jlink

Yes, this is possible [with `jlink`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jlink.htm#JSWOR-GUID-CECAC52B-CFEE-46CB-8166-F17A8E9280E9) ([JEP 282](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/282)), but all of your code *and* your dependencies need to be modular JARs (i.e. ones with `module-info.class`). It works like this:

```
jlink
    --module-path $JAVA_HOME/jmods:mods
    --add-modules your.app
    --launcher launch-app=your.app
    --output your-app-image
```

In detail:

- `--module-path` lists the folders that contain modules - this needs to include the platform modules shipped with the JDK you want to use (in `$JAVA_HOME/jmods`) and your application modules (`mods`)
- `--add-modules` names the module(s) that you want your runtime image to contain - all of its (their) transitive dependencies are included
- `--launcher` is optional, but very handy; it creates an OS-specific launcher (e.g. a `.bat` on Windows) with the given name (`launch-app`) that launches the specified module (`your.app`; in this case assuming the main class is defined for it)
- `--output` specifies where to create the runtime image

Comment: It is also interesting how `jlink` is different to `javapackager` in terms of what you can do to create a self-contained application. Any chance you can update your answer to include information about `javapackager` too?

Comment: the launcher can also be a native executable file. for windows this is a better solution than the bat file because it can also include resources as an app icon.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov I've never used `javapackager` and would have to research it. Why don't you write an answer about that one? :)

Comment: @Nicolai Because I haven't used it as well

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer!  This will definitely change embedded systems as we know it.

Comment: According to the new [`javapackager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/deploy/self-contained-application-packaging.htm#JSDPG583) page, it uses `jlink` internally. So for a real self-contained application with executables, use javapackager.

Comment: Recent releases (i.e. Java 14+), replaced the javapackager tool mentioned in comments on this question with a new tool named [jpackage](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/392) which "Supports native packaging formats to give end users a natural installation experience", unlike jlink, it supports packaging for both modular and non-modular applications.

Answer (score 11):

#### jpackage:

As an edit (pointed in comments), `javapackager` was removed from JDK in Java-10 and one can look forward to making use of [**`jpackage`**](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/343) as an incubating tool since Java-14.

#### javapackager

You can use **[`javapackager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/javapackager.htm#JSWOR719)** tool.

> The Java packaging tools provide built-in support for several formats
>   of self-contained application packages.
>
> The basic package is a single
>   folder on your hard drive that includes all application resources and
>   the JRE. The package can be redistributed as is, or you can build an
>   installable package (for example, EXE or DMG format.)

Though there are certain restrictions associated with building these applications with `javapackager` which includes -

- Self-contained application packages must be explicitly requested by passing the native argument to the  Ant task or javapackager -deploy command.
- Self-contained application packages must be *built on the operating system on which it is intended to run*. Prerequisite tools must be available to build a package in a specific format.
- Self-contained application packages can only be built using JDK 7 Update 6 or later. *The Java Packager for JDK 9 packages applications with a JDK 9 runtime image. To package a JDK 8 or JDK 7 JRE with your application, use the JDK 8 Java Packager*.

---

One way to create a basic self-contained application is to modify the [`deploy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/deploy/javafx-ant-tasks.htm#JSDPG179) ant task:-

```
<fx:deploy width="${javafx.run.width}" height="${javafx.run.height}"
           nativeBundles="all"
           outdir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" outfile="${application.title}">
    <fx:application name="${application.title}" mainClass="${javafx.main.class}"/>
    <fx:resources>
        <fx:fileset dir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
    </fx:resources>
    <fx:info title="${application.title}" vendor="${application.vendor}"/>
</fx:deploy>
```

Native packages can be built using the [`javapackager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/javapackager.htm#JSWOR719) command tool. Java Packager Command to Generate Self-Contained Application Packages would be something like -

```
javapackager -deploy -native -outdir OUTPUT_DIR -outfile APPLICATION_NAME 
    -srcdir PACKAGE_SRC_DIR -srcfiles APPLICATION.jar -appclass MAIN_CLASS
    -name "YourApplication" -title "SelfContained"
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.
It includes JRE in the application folder and creates an executable file.
I had my file java files in the src folder and this command compiled and created a dist folder with an executable file.

```
javapackager -makeall -name WordAnalyzer_app -appclass queue.Gui
pause
```